# Not Showing the output of Json Data from controller to the view

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json, razor

I am trying to to show the Json data from controller to the view. It works fine in my test project, but when I copied the work in the main project it gives error.

It says Url does not exist in the current context. Although it works fine in the test project and doesn't give this error.

Controller Code -

```
public JsonResult GetFreight()
{
    string url = "https://digitalapi.auspost.com.au/postage/parcel/domestic/calculate.json?length=22&to_postcode=3000&from_postcode=2000&weight=1.5&height=7.7&width=16&service_code=AUS_PARCEL_REGULAR";

    //synchronous client.
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers.Add("auth-key:a1234567-abcd-abcd-1234-1234567890abc");
    var content = client.DownloadString(url);
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var jsonContent = serializer.Deserialize<Object>(content);

    return Json(jsonContent, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

View Code

```
<script>
    var weather = Object();
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.get("@Url.Action("GetFreight", "ShoppingCart")", function (response) {
        //response
        console.log(response);
        weather = ko.mapping.fromJS(response);  //populate the weather object
        ko.applyBindings(weather);
    });
});
</script>

<td>Freight = <span data-bind="text:postage_result.total_cost"></span></td>
```

I want to mention one more thing- In the main project the view is placed in another subfolder called "ShoppingCart" so do I need to change anything in the script when calling the method from the controller? Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that it is a good idea to post url and auth key in your source? To your question: In which file and folder is the `GetFreight`located and what it is set up as your default route?

Comment: This auth key is for testing purpose and GetFreight is located in Controller Folder and ShoppingCartController File. My default route is the HomeController/index